# Creating a p:dialog that has dynamic header

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I'm trying to create a dialog that has dynamic header. the behaviour desired is:

When I click on the button I update the value of a variable (`var`) in the backing bean and call a method (`updateDialogHeader`) that sets another variable (`headerDialog`) to a text depending on the value of (`var`). This same button will show a dialog that its header is equal to the contenent
 of `headerDialog`.

I use the following code:

**XHTML page**

```
<h:form>
<p:commandButton value="?" update="formDialog" action="#{backingBean.methodUpdate (1)}" oncomplete="myDialog.show()"/>
</h:form>

<h:form id="formDialog">
<p:dialog widgetVar="myDialog" position="center" modal="true" header="#{backingBean.headerDialog}" width="400" >
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

**Backing bean**

```
public void methodUpdate (int param) {
        var= param;
        headerDialog = updateHeaderDialog();
    }

public String updateHeaderDialog() {
if (var== 1) {
            return "Header one";
        }
        if (var== 2) {
            return "Header two";
        }
   return "";
}
```

Using the rpevious code shows superimposed dialogs the 1st dialog is a dialog without header, the 2nd is the desired dialog (with the proper header). Clicking again on the button shows 3 dialogs the 1st one is the desired, the 2nd a dialog without header and the 3rd is the desired dialog with header. Notice, the more I click the more I get more dialogs.

Please help me. I don't understand where am I mistaking.

Comment: Maybe your mistake is this line action="#{backingBean.methodUpdate (1)}". You always send the param "1" means it will always set the same HEadertext

Comment: @Ovoxo thanks for the comment. In fact, in my situation I've many buttons each button is supposed to set a different header. I've put a sout in the method and its working. The dialog displays the desired header but the real problem is in the rendered dialog, please check the last paragraph where I describe how the dialog is rendered.

Comment: Do I understand right? For each button-click you want a new Dialog? 1st-Click = 1 Dialog, 2nd-Click = 2 Dialog?

Comment: @Ovoxo what u said isn't what I want, it's the problem that I'm facing. Clicking on the button for the 1st time shows 2 superimposed dialogs (which is a problem, I'm supposed to have 1 dialog only). Feel free to  read the full description of my problem in the last paragraph  =)